# Ajax Element return full html code

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I couldnt figure out whats wrong with my code but if I am calling ajax with the following code:

ajax.js:

```
function ajaxObj(meth, url){
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open(meth, url, true);
x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www_form-urlencoded");
return x;
}

function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
    return true;
    }
}
```

signup.php

```
function checkusername(){
            var u = _("username").value;
            if( u != ""){
                _("usernamestatus").innerHTML = "checking...";
                var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
                ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true){
                        _("usernamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    }
                }
                ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
            }
        }
```

The PHP code I am calling is the following in signup.php:

```
<?php
    //ajax calls usernamecheck
    if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
        include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
        $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if(strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
            echo '<strong style = "color:#F00;">3 - 16 characters please</strong>';
            exit();
        }
        if(is_numeric($username[0])){
            echo '<strong style = "color:#F00;">Username must begin with a letter!</strong>';
            exit();
        }
        if($uname_check < 1){
            echo '<strong style = "color:#09900;">' . $username . ' is OK</strong>';
            exit();
        } else {
            echo '<strong style = "color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

As you can see, it is just a check for the username in SignUp form.

The function `_(x)` is getting the Element by ID.

I get the full HTML code as response and not the echo.

If I use the following:

```
<?php
//ajax calls usernamecheck
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
    echo 'test';
}
```

then it returns test + full html.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. If the page you called has HTML in it everything will be returned, that is how AJAX works. Try isolating the PHP you want to call in a separate file with no HTML markup.

Comment: Side note `x-www_form-urlencoded` is not a proper content type, it should be `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Putting the PHP into separate file and then calling only that file is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OhGodwhy had the right answer.
It was exactly the typo in "x-www_form-urlencoded" which should be "x-www-form-urlencoded".

Answer (score 1):

You should use `exit()` only once, at the end of your AJAX backend call, so that the script would terminate and nothing else would be sent to the browser. E.g.,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
    echo 'test'; // or whatever complex logic should be here
    exit();
}
```

would do the trick.